# .NET MapHealthCheck() responds with index.html instead of json data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, health-monitoring, health-check

**Question:**

I recently added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks to my .NET with react application, but when I run my frontend and backend and go to the url for my healthCheck it's just a blank page and as a respone I get my index.html file.
The same Error occurs when imake a GET-Request in Postman.

---

**Code**

My `setup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    //... some code

    services.AddHealthChecks();

    //... some code
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    var response = HealthCheckUtils.CreateResponse(report);
                    var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, new      JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonString);
                }
            });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller=Home}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

---

**Question:**

Does someone have an idea of how to solve it?

---

**Notes:**

I you need any more code snippets or informations, please do not hesitate to ask.

---

**Problem Summary:**

When i call endpoints.MapHealthCheck("/health") it responds with my index.html file instead of the json data.

Comment: Are you using a login/authorization service? This might be blocking direct requests towards the address you are targetting

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but I would first check if the health check code is even running. Put a breakpoint here: `var response = HealthCheckUtils.CreateResponse(report);` and see if you hit it when you call `health` endpoint

Comment: When you say `index.html`, what exactly do you mean? I don't see an `app.UseStaticFiles()` that would serve any html files up. How are you hosting this app? Sounds like maybe whatever you're usingto host  is serving up the file without hitting the asp.net runtime.

Comment: @Roe i do have an authorization service, but it is disabled. I already figured that this could restrict something but even without it doesn't work.

Comment: @KorayElbek strange... when I place a breakpoint at the line u said, it doe NOT get called. If I put a breakpoint at the line 'endpoints.MapHealthCheck("/health", new ...' and then press F11 (Step into) it instantly goes to the next endpoints.MapcontrollerRoute(..." Don't know why bubt that is definitely something i have to "investigate" further

Comment: @ChrisPickford I do not have an app.UseStaticFiles() but SpaConfig.Add(services) and SpaConfig.Use(_env, app). Maybe that's a reason for this mess. But i didnt implement the services.AddSpaStaticFiles() function so that's aout of the way...

Comment: You can solve this problem using this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.SmartInject#health-check-result-in-json